# How do i add verification for data in couchbase server(windows) (on server side)?

Tags: c#, .net, database, couchbase

Lets say i have a client and a couchdb server(on windows). 
the client is a small game.

lets say the user wants to buy something, the client check if u have enough money and if u do send a request to the server. on the server i have a table with username, money, items.
if u have enough money i would update the money and gives +1 for items.

at this point i would like the server to check itself if u have enough money.
and actually do the updates itself.
(i figure its more secure), so i wanna add some verification function somewhere, but have no idea where.

i have looked for information on this subject but could not find any. maybe because i am lacking in understanding of the basics, and of what to look for.

how do i do that with couchbase? what tools do i need. (im using mostly .net but not limited to)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do that with couchbase.

use can use a .net web service to query /update the couchbase database and connect the client to the web service.

this way all logic is on the server side (on the web service) you only call the web service from the client. also its quite easy as all sides allow you to pass serialized classes between them.

good luck kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

In Couchbase Server you do not have server side validation/constraints. So what you have to do in your case it to get this business logic into your application.

This should not be a problem at all, your application will be able to use the "get" operation that is a very fast operation into the "user wallet/profile" (that is probably already in memory) and be able to check if the users has enough money to buy the item.

Comment: but that would be exposing the database connection to the client. is it not better for example to have some asp.net service or webpage having that logic on the server? is there no equivilant for that in couchbase itself? thank you!

Comment: I think that is what Tug is suggesting, is that the only connection to Couchbase should be from your .NET web service. Couchbase plays the role of a standard database here, you're app is responsible for your business logic.